# Django query for foreign key relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Let's say, I have Three models in Django

User

- name
- username

Dog

- name
- owner ForeignKey(User)

Cat

- name
- owner Foreignkey(User)

Now my question is -

count how many owner have dogs and cats, with django orm? or total number of owners who have dogs and cats.

What kind of joining it will be?

Answer (score 2):

You have to count the number of dogs and cats for each user with `annotate` and then filter where that number is greater than 0.

```
from django.db.models import Count


User.objects.annotate(
    has_dog=Count('dog'),
    has_cat=Count('cat')
).filter(
    has_dog__gt=0,
    has_cat__gt=0
).count()
```

Comment: Can you please add some context and explanation to your answer?

Comment: +1 It is also important to add an [empty `order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by) for the case that the model could have a default ordering.